# Minimum area of a regular $n$-gon containing a bounded $C^1$ curve

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, curves

Imagine a ${C^1}$ curve $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and given $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is there a way of finding the area of the regular n-gon where the area of this bounding n-gon is minimised ?

Comment: You mean you consider regular n-gons in which the curve is totally included ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean . Sorry I should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be more precise, therefore possibly attracting more readers.